# button_to doesn't open confirmation dialog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following link to update the status of an application on my app.  The model is called `hardships` (i.e. a `hardship` == a single application) and the method in my `hardships_controller.rb` is like this:

```
 def withdraw_application
    @hardship = Hardship.find(params[:id])
    @hardship.update_attributes(status: "Withdrawn")
    if @hardship.update_attributes(status: "Withdrawn")
        redirect_back(fallback_location: user_path(current_user))
        flash[:notice] = "That application has been withdrawn!"
    else
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
        flash[:warning] = "Something went wrong.  Please try your request again later."
    end
  end
```

I have this line in my routes:

```
post "hardships/:id/withdraw_application" => "hardships#withdraw_application", as: "withdraw_application"
```

And I'm calling it with a `button_to` link.  (I'd prefer a `link_to`, but apparently those don't function via `post` anymore?):

```
<% @hardships.each do |hardship| %>
   ...
   <%= button_to "Withdraw", withdraw_application_path(hardship), method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to withdraw your application?"} %>
<% end %>
```

The desired behavior is that it pop up a confirmation button and then update the status of the `hardship` to "Withdrawn".  However, it doesn't pop up the confirmation dialog box and just processes the method right away.

Can anyone see why this dialogue isn't occurring?  Ideally, I'd love it to live in the controller not the link, but any functioning dialog would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you just not getting the confirmation dialog box or is your controller method `withdraw_application` also not called? Is the generated html by the `button_to` helper correct (compared to the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to))?

Comment: @josien Everything is working perfectly except there's no confirmation dialog box. The method is getting called properly.

Comment: Doesn't related to the problem, but why do you call `update_attributes` in the controller twice?

Comment: Could this be a browser specific thing - does it not work in all browsers? Also, could it have to do with some browser addon?

Comment: @Josien Unfortunately not.  I've tried live and in localhost on multiple browsers.